# Sencha Touch 1.x, how to create a container with two components using hbox

Tags: layout, components, containers, extjs, hbox

I have a set of data in my dataStore, and I output my data using textfields within containers in a .js view. I also disabled the fields only to show data and be uneditable. I was wondering if there are any alternatives to using 'xtype: textfield', and 'xtype: textareafield' ?

With this question entailed, I'm trying to create a container with two components using hbox as such an alternative, and this is the code that I have of the following:

```
    var formContainer1 = new Ext.Container({
        width: '100%',
        height: '65%',            
        layout: {
            type: 'vbox',
        //    type: 'hbox',
            align: 'stretch',
        },
        defaults: {
            labelAlign:'left',            
        //    labelWidth:'30%',
            labelWidth:'25%',
        },
        items: [
            { 
                bodyStyle: "background-color: #52ABD5;", //Color = Light Blue
                html: '<font face="Helvetica" size="4" color="white" ><p>Information</p>'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
            //    xtype: 'component',
                name: 'Description',
                disabled: true,
                label: 'Desc',                    
            },{
                xtype: 'textfield',
            //    xtype: 'component',
                name: 'Number',
                disabled: true,
                label: 'ANumber',
                id: 'ANumber',
            },{
                xtype: 'textareafield',
            //    xtype: 'component',
                name: 'directions',
                disabled: true,
                label: 'Directions',
                height: 'auto',
            //    defaults: {
                    //required: true,
            //        labelAlign: 'left',
            //        labelWidth: '100%'
            //    },                        
            },
        ],
    /*    dockedItems: [
            {
                layout: 'hbox',
                xtype: 'toolbar',
                dock: 'top',
                title: 'Information',
            //    scroll: 'horizontal',
            }
        ]*/
    });
```

Now this code works just fine, except i don't want to use 'textfield' or 'textareafield'. I'm still using those because I tried using xtype: component, but it didn't work. Also when I tried this in hbox layout, it didn't show up like I wanted it to (row after row). I'm pretty sure I'm just not understanding the "components using hbox" part because yeah I want this container to look really close to this:

Img url: http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2683/5852914556_b2886e3363.jpg

(note: referring to the right most iphone picture w/ the containers)

Please clarify for me on the "w/ 2 components usnig hbox" part. Thanks!

By the way: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?186243-Alternatives-to-textfield&p=759843#post759843

My username on that post: kevinjset. This was the original post that I posted on Sencha touch forums asking the same question, I just wanted to see if you guys on Stack Overflow! can help me out too! Thanks, appeciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly tedious but it might help you out

```
{
            xtype:'fieldset',
            title:'fieldset1',
            items:[{
                xtype:'container',
                layout:'hbox',
                items:[{
                    xtype:'container',
                    flex:1,
                    html:'1'
                },{
                    xtype:'container',
                    flex:1,
                    html:'2'
                },{
                    xtype:'container',
                    flex:1,
                    html:'3'
                }]
            },{
                xtype:'container',
                layout:'hbox',
                items:[{
                    xtype:'container',
                    flex:1,
                    html:'4'
                },{
                    xtype:'container',
                    flex:1,
                    html:'4'
                },{
                    xtype:'container',
                    flex:1,
                    html:'6'
                }]
            }]
        }
```